# List of all unsupported commands in redis cluster

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

I can't find complete list of all commands which may be unsupported by redis cluster (as example EVAL which i technically can execute if all keys point to the same slot). I think it's nice to have this list, as it helps to migrate your codebase from redis to redis-cluster.

Answer (score 3):

All commands are supported AFAIR, except for `SELECT`.

Multi-key commands, transactions and Lua scripts are special because if you use them you have to make sure that all keys referenced are mapped to the same slot (with hashtags for example). `EVAL`, BTW, requires all keys as input precisely because of that consideration - if you're programmatically generating your key names then you're using it wrong :)